# Nftables firewall rule hex value 0x1fff changed to decimal 8191

Tags: firewall, nftables

I started the process of migrating into nftables, just noticed that while I add this rule

```
add rule netdev filter INGRESS ip frag-off & 0x1fff != 0 counter drop
```

should look like this in nftables.conf

```
ip frag-off & 0x1fff != 0 counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
```

looks like that instead

```
ip frag-off & 8191 != 0 counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
```

I know it's decimal equivalence of hexadecimal value 0x1fff, just wonder why does it happen and will it affect the rule itself in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manpage defines:

> INTEGER TYPE
>
> The integer type is used for numeric values. It may be specified as a
> decimal, hexadecimal or octal number. The integer type does not have a
> fixed size, its size is determined by the expression for which it is
> used.

You may enter the value in decimal, hexadecimal or octal, but the value is
still the same.

The software chooses to display integer values as decimal,
there is no other significance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that seems right, I also found this, while it doesn't answer this question in particular, also gives a clue about it

```
> nft: Fix add_bitwise_u16() on Big Endian Type used for 'mask' and
> 'xor' parameters was wrong, 'int' is four bytes on 32 or 64 bit
> architectures. After casting a uint16_t to int, on Big Endian the
> first two bytes of data are (the leading) zero which libnftnl then
> copies instead of the actual value.

This problem was noticed when using '--fragment' option:

    | # iptables-nft -A FORWARD --fragment -j ACCEPT
    | # nft list ruleset | grep frag-off
    | ip frag-off & 0 != 0 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept

With this fix in place, the resulting nft rule is correct:

    | ip frag-off & 8191 != 0 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

> Fixes: 2f1fbab671576 ("iptables: nft: add -f support") Signed-off-by:
> Phil Sutter <phil@nwl.cc> Acked-by: Pablo Neira Ayuso
> <pablo@netfilter.org>
```

[Source](https://git.netfilter.org/iptables/commit/?id=7c64eaf4b1b97ff69a7d9c5c13d4e9eff97d2cd1) patch applied to a netfilter regarding bad iptables translation, but like I said it gives a clue to my question about
0x1fff = 8191

Also if anyone come across an error like this while adding a rule

nft add rule netdev filter INGRESS ip frag-off & 0x1fff != 0 counter drop

```
-su: 8191: command not found
 root@serv:/etc# Error: syntax error, unexpected newline
 add rule netdev filter INGRESS ip frag-off
                                           ^
    
[1]+  Exit 1                  nft add rule netdev filter INGRESS ip frag-off
```

it's due to shell interpreter, the solution is to use nft -i or
either one of those escaping special character "&" or using "and" instead

```
nft add rule netdev filter INGRESS ip frag-off and 0x1fff != 0 counter drop

nft add rule netdev filter INGRESS ip frag-off \& 0x1fff != 0 counter drop
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).